# Need to find and delete duplicate or more occurrence of same nodes(exact copy of node ) over for loop

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

```
Input:

    <relations>
      <relation>
        <isIdenticalInternationalStandardOf id="AssetID" metadataStatus="Publishable">1234</isIdenticalInternationalStandardOf>
        <isIdenticalInternationalStandardOf id="PrimaryDesignator">abc</isIdenticalInternationalStandardOf>
      </relation>
      <relation>
         <isIdenticalRegionalStandardOf id="AssetID" metadataStatus="Publishable">1234</isIdenticalRegionalStandardOf>
         <isIdenticalRegionalStandardOf id="PrimaryDesignator">abc</isIdenticalRegionalStandardOf>
      </relation>
      <relation>
        <supersededBy id="AssetID" metadataStatus="Publishable">5647</supersededBy>
        <supersededBy id="PrimaryDesignator">pqr</supersededBy>
      </relation>
      <relation>
        <replacedBy id="AssetID" metadataStatus="Publishable">1234</replacedBy>
        <replacedBy id="PrimaryDesignator">abc</replacedBy>
      </relation>
      <relation>
        <supersededBy id="AssetID" metadataStatus="Publishable">1234</supersededBy>
        <supersededBy id="PrimaryDesignator">xyz</supersededBy>
      </relation>
      <relation>
        <isIdenticalInternationalStandardOf id="AssetID" metadataStatus="Publishable">1234</isIdenticalInternationalStandardOf>
        <isIdenticalInternationalStandardOf id="PrimaryDesignator">abc</isIdenticalInternationalStandardOf>
      </relation>
       <relation>
        <isIdenticalInternationalStandardOf id="AssetID" metadataStatus="Publishable">1234</isIdenticalInternationalStandardOf>
        <isIdenticalInternationalStandardOf id="PrimaryDesignator">abc</isIdenticalInternationalStandardOf>
      </relation>
    </relations>
```

I could able to find duplicate from Input, here is code:

```
let $data := $each-search-copy/relations
let $map := map:map()
let $uniqueList :=
      for $outer at $i in $data/relation
          for $inner at $j in $data/relation
               where $i ne $j
                  return 
                     if(fn:deep-equal($outer, $inner)) then
                     if(fn:exists(map:get($map, xs:string($j)))) then () else map:put($map, xs:string($i), xs:string($j)) 
                     else ()

let $duplicate :=
      for $each at $i in $data/relation
          return 
            if(fn:exists(map:get($map, xs:string($i)))) 
              then (
                     fn:string-join((xdmp:quote($each), "&#10;"), "|")
                    ) else ()
```

finding duplicate node is done, Now I want to write update transaction query which will keep only unique list of nodes.
if multiple occurrence is there then it should get deleted.

with the help of MAP construct I could delete if duplicate is there but not multiple occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the nodes by invoking the [`xdmp:node-delete()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-delete) function for each of the nodes that you want to remove.

You can identify those duplicate elements a little more simply and succinctly in a single for loop, and a `where` clause that tests whether the `relationship` element is `deep-equal()` to any of it's `relationship` siblings, excluding the current `relationship` element being processed in the for loop by ensuring that the `generate-id()` values (guaranteed to be the same for the same node) are not equal:

```
let $all-relations := $each-search-copy/relations/relation
return
  for $relation in $all-relations
  where $all-relations[fn:deep-equal(., $relation) and generate-id(.) ne generate-id($relation)]
  return xdmp:node-delete($relation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the duplicates, you can just rebuild the de-duplicated list and do a single replacement. e.g. iterate through the list and output every relation that hasn't been seen before.

```
let $uniqueList :=
  for $outer at $i in $data/relation
  where every $inner in ($data/relation)[1 to $i - 1]
    satisfies fn:not(fn:deep-equal($inner, $outer))
  return $outer

return xdmp:node-replace($data, <relations>{ $uniqueList }</relations>)
```